# HTML/CSS - Format subordinate elements

Tags: html, css

I have a really basic question but I'm not sure how to express it, so I'll just try:

I have a table on my website, which looks like this:

```
<table class="display" width="100%">

.display td tr th
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

I want to format the subordinate elements of my table (td, tr, th) without writing `<td class="display">` for each td element.

I don't wanna change td, tr or th because I'm using other tables on my site, which shouldn't be affected.

Can somebody help me?

Shivan

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
table.display > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: No. Look at any page's DOM. See the `<tbody>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit lengthy, but...

```
.display>thead>tr>td, .display>thead>tr>th,
  .display>tbody>tr>td, .display>tbody>tr>th,
  .display>tfoot>tr>td, .display>tfoot>tr>th,
  .display>tr>td, .display>tr>th {
    /* apply styles here */
}
```

This will apply the styles only to the cells belonging to the right table (the one with `class="display"`).

Once CSS4 is widely available, you will be able to do:

```
.display>:matches(thead,tbody,tfoot)>tr>:matches(td,th) {
    /* apply styles here */
}
```

Comment: Why is the child combinator (`>`) required, surely `.display td, .display th` would be sufficent?

Comment: @DavidThomas Nested tables.

Comment: Where are nested tables specified, was the question edited? (I'm not trying to be obnoxious, and future-proofing against nested tables may well be a good idea, but as-written the question doesn't seem to imply the requirement.)

Comment: That's true, it doesn't, but this is a good thing to future-proof - I went years not knowing how to do this and it was not pretty! XD